# Connection Error: javax.microedition.io.ConnectionNotFoundException:TCP open

Tags: java, tcp

I posted this error here cuz it has been disturbing me for long time whenever i try to connect to my web api from my j2me application.I just would like to share this if somebody has same problem as me.

Answer (score 1):

When this error happened to me, it was because my web server (tomcat) was not running. Make sure that your web server is up and running then try again.

Answer (score 0):

my solution to this error is i changed in host file which is located at C:\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\ and i opened the ip that i m trying to call.
the other attempt i did if this one is not working is check the instances whether they are already run or not. This is also one option which really did solve the TCP open error.

Comment: I did not specify what u r saying, because I also get this error but i am not solve so replay me how to solve this error